# Is there a way to prevent rounding in opencv matrix divison

Tags: c++, opencv

I have an integer matrix and I want to perform an integer division on it. But opencv always rounds the result.
I know I can divide each element manually but I want to know is there a better way for this or not?

```
Mat c = (Mat_ <int> (1,3) << 80,71,64 );
cout << c/8 << endl;

// result
//[10, 9, 8]

// desired result
//[10, 8, 8]
```

Comment: Both your solutions have rounding - the first defaults to "round to nearest" or "round up" and the second to "round down" or "round to zero". We can't tell the rounding mode from just one example, of course.

Comment: I want to truncate like when you divide an integer by another integer.

Comment: Truncating (`-7.7 => -7` and `+7.7 =>+7`)  is equivalent to "round to zero"

Comment: What I want is exactly integer division and I think that is equivalent to applying `floor` to it. `-7.7 => -8` and `+7.7 => 7`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to @GPPK's optional method, you can hack it by:

```
Mat tmp, dst;
c.convertTo(tmp, CV_64F);
tmp = tmp / 8 - 0.5;            // simulate to prevent rounding by -0.5
tmp.convertTo(dst, CV_32S);

cout << dst;
```

Comment: Very helpful. I wonder if is faster than iterating over all the elements or not?

Comment: @sudomakeinstall2 To be honest, I'm not quite sure about this. It will be faster if OpenCV has done some optimization on the Mat type conversion. Anyway, you can timing it to find it out. :P

Comment: Keep in mind that CV_32F only has 22 bits of precision. This rounding won't work reliably for numbers over 8 million.

Comment: @MSalters Change to `CV_64F`. Thanks. :P

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with using `ints`, you cant have decimal points with `ints` so I'm not sure how you are expecting not to get rounding.

You really have two options here, **I do not think you can this without using one of these options**:

1. You have a mathematically correct `int` matrix division `[10, 9, 8]`
2. You spin up your own divide function in order to give you the result you want.

**Option 2:**

Pseudocode:

```
Create a double matrix
perform the division to get the output [10.0, 8.875, 8.0]
strip away any numbers after a decimal point [10.0, 8.0, 8.0]
(optional) write these values back to a int matrix
(result) [10, 8, 8]
```

Comment: As I said in the question, I don't want to use `for`.

Comment: I dont think you can do this any other way, or I would have posted it. I have updated my question