# Dividing cv::Mat by a number using integer division

Tags: c++, opencv

In OpenCV if `cv::Mat (CV_8U)` was divided by a number (`int`) the result will be rounded to the nearest number for example:

```
cv::Mat temp(1, 1, CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(5));
temp /= 3;
std::cout <<"OpenCV Integer Division:" << temp;
std::cout << "\nNormal Integer Division:" << 5 / 3;
```

The result is:

> OpenCV Integer Division: 2
>
> Normal Integer Division: 1

It is obvious that OpenCV does not use integer division even if the type of the `cv::Mat` is `CV_8U`.

**My questions are:**

- Why? Is not supposed for integers to be divided as integers. Why this strange behaviour of OpenCV?
- Can I obtain integer division without iterating pixel by pixel and dividing it?

**My current solution is:**

```
for (size_t r = 0; r < temp.rows; r++){
    auto row_ptr = temp.ptr<uchar>(r);
    for (size_t c = 0; c < temp.cols; c++){
        row_ptr[c] /= 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: Very similar to question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30833540/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-rounding-in-opencv-matrix-divison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I used to solve it is: (depending on @Afshine answer and @Miki comment):

```
if (frame.isContinuous()){
    for(int i = 0; i < frame.total(); i++){
       frame.data[i]/=3;
    }
}
else{
    for (size_t r = 0; r < frame.rows; r++){
        auto row_ptr = frame.ptr<uchar>(r);
        for (size_t c = 0; c < 3 * frame.cols; c++){
            row_ptr[c] /= 3;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

firstly : the overloaded operator for Division does the operation by converting the elements of matrix into double. it originally uses multiplication operator as: Mat / a =Mat * (1/a).
secondly : a very easy way exists to do this by one small for loop:

```
   for(int i=0;i<temp.total();i++)
        ((unsigned char*)temp.data)[i]/=3;
```

Comment: This won't work for non continuous matrices. @Humam "current solution" is better ;D

Comment: @Miki ! you are right ... the continuity must be checked first.. . .